# Automatically track the position of a Label inside a scrollable Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label, panel

I have some Labels in a Panel (see figure A).

After entering a search term in a TextBox, the term will be marked in the Panel.
You could move to the item you are looking for using the Scrollbar (see figure B).

How could this happen automatically, after the User has entered a search term in the TextBox?
The Panel should scroll to the Label that has been *marked* (without User intervention).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = textBox1.Text;

    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
       {
            if (c.Name.Contains(search))
            {
                c.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but control does not contain a definition for BringToView. I tried with c.BringToFront() without success… In the property window (Windows Forms) of course, each label has a name. Without giving a name, the code would not work

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking WPF :(. In winforms, I think you can modify `scrollbar.value` to the position of your label in your scrollable panel

Comment: Don’t worry : ) Unfortunately I do not know how to modify my code. I  just set AutoScroll to true in the properties window.

Comment: When yo usay "normal"are you referring to a "panel" or a "flowlayoutpanel".  The flowlayout panel does not have all the features of a regular panel.  I've given up using a flowlayoutpanel for this reason.  I just build my own layoutpanel by creating a main panel and adding an array of child panels.

Comment: You can loop `panel1.Controls.OfType<label>()`, add Controls that match the criteria to a `List<Control>`, then - if the list is not empty - call `panel1.ScrollControlIntoView([YourList[0]]);` -- `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) return;` should be the first line in that method, not inside the loop.

Comment: If you use a FlowLayoutPanel you can use `flowLayoutPanel1ScrollControlIntoView()`

Comment: Many thanks for the tip "jedweng".

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I get it, Jimi : )

Comment: I shall try, "TaW".  Thanks for your hint : )